# Updating the apache tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently the [apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apache) is [synonym-ed](https://serverfault.com/tags/apache-2.2/synonyms) to [apache-2.2](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apache-2.2).

While perhaps useful in the past, it has since lost its usefulness. As [apache-2.4](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apache-2.4) exists now, and the general [apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apache) tag is misleading to those who don't immediately specify their version.

*Suggestions:*
Remove the apache tag synonym, and ban it (is this possible?).
Remove the synonym and create the tag, with a descriptor of what apache is, referencing the other two tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, the apache tag is now blacklisted:

[image]

Along with this comes the requirement that a version-specific tag *exists* for each Apache version being asked about. In practice, this isn't likely to be too different from what was already occurring (since the raw apache tag was being silently renamed to apache-2.2), but be aware that some amount of confusion or mistagging may result - so be prepared to retag (and create new tags) as needed.

Answer (score 12):

The apache tag should be blacklisted. Apache 2.2 and 2.4 (and there are still a few freaks out there using 1.3!) are sufficiently different that people usually need to specify the version they are using.

(Moderators can't blacklist a tag, though; SE will need to be called in.)

Comment: They share a lot of syntax and many answers are applicable to either.  Making this overly specific is not intuitive for newbs and it prevents post-newbs from categorizing things properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it would be handy to have a generic `apache-2.x` tag for answers which are not specific to a particular subversion of apache.  I just had [one of those](https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/199626) a few minutes ago.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. The problem is, users who ask questions here are often not experienced enough to know whether their question is specific to an Apache version, and this extra tag will just confuse them (and the rest of us). They will often get it wrong.

Comment: Might want to get rid of the [tag:apache-2.x] and [tag:apache-1.x] tags then, @MichaelHampton. Adding an appropriate 1.... tag as needed.

Comment: @Shog9 They are gotten rid of.

Comment: I'm glad Michael is happy.  Trying to make things easier is a laudable goal, but this is removing the sharp edges from a useful tool.  That's carrying things too far for my tastes, but treating ops folks like children is often effective.

Comment: In my experience, sysops and children have an awful lot of common ground, @chicks... Implementing the blacklist.

Comment: @chicks If only everyone asking questions on Server Fault was "ops folks". Unfortunately most are not.

Comment: Regardless of how we perceive the site's audience we are making things more confusing by people finding a question that is generic to apache is tagged with a later subversion than they are using.

Answer (score -4):

What about other Apache things like Solr, Tomcat, or even the Apache Foundation? How is having Apache linked to the Apache 2.2 web server helpful?

Comment: It's not and it's not.

Comment: I thinl you need to read this thread again...